# What is the most efficient way to stack two columns into one, perform calculations, and unstack the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {
    "x" : [636, -636, -636, 636],
    "y" : [-636, -636, 636, 636],
    "s" : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "t" : [5, 6, 7, 8]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

For further processing I need to "stack" the data into following format:

```
taget = {
    "x" : [636, -636, -636, 636, 636, -636, -636, 636],
    "y" : [-636, -636, 636, 636, -636, -636, 636, 636],
    "vals" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
}
```

After all calculations I need to revert this stacking and return to two columns.
My solution (see below) is working fine but does not "feel" pythonic and efficient.
Any suggestions how to improve my code?

```
import pandas as pd

# origin df
data = {
    "x" : [636, -636, -636, 636],
    "y" : [-636, -636, 636, 636],
    "s" : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "t" : [5, 6, 7, 8]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# 'combine' columns
x = df["x"].tolist() + df["x"].tolist()
y = df["y"].tolist() + df["y"].tolist()
vals = df["s"].tolist() + df["t"].tolist()

# create new df with combined columns
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "x" : x,
    "y" : y,
    "vals" : vals
})

# process vals...doing some crazy math

# unstack the prior combined column
ss = newdf.loc[:(len(newdf)/2)-1]["vals"].tolist()
tt = newdf.loc[(len(newdf)/2):]["vals"].tolist()

df["ss"] = ss
df["tt"] = tt

print(df)
```

Comment: `df.melt(['x', 'y'], value_name='vals').drop(columns='variable')`